# Need a formula to get PSI from ADC chip

Tags: calculus

I am creating a system to remotely read the pressure from an oil filtration system. It has an analog 0-100psi gauge. I've added a "T" so I could attach a pressure transmitter and an analog to digital converter through a raspberry pi using python. That's the backstory to paint you a picture. Here's the data:

```
psi     ADC "value"
10      45  
20      66
30      88
40      112
```

I get the ADC "value" (let's call it X) from the python program.  I need a formula where I can give it X and get psi.

Thanks so much!

Comment: @Andrei has the right answer. An online calculator gives $\text{PSI} = 0.44802\times\text{ADC} - 9.83325$. If you need greater accuracy, at least this is a place to begin. Good luck with your project!

Comment: What are PSI and ADC ? Your answer will help me to go to bed a little less stupid than when I waked up.

Comment: PSI is pounds per square inch and ADC is the value that the freenove.com Analog to Digital Converter chip gives me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data falls almost perfectly on a straight line. Calculate the best fit using least square approximation. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression for example
[image]

Comment: You are the man! I knew I'd feel dumb once I saw the equation. Feel good about yourself. You helped someone in need. Thank you.